# Switch and outlet wiring help

Tags: electrical

thanks in advance for any help here.

I am in CA and these two boxes are in my garage.  The switch is right by the door to enter the house.  The other box is a GFCI outlet on one of the walls.  The wiring was like this when I bought the house.  The switch does absolutely nothing, I've been looking for over five years.  It does not control half an outlet, power any outdoor lights, etc.  The GFCI works fine with no issues.

I have a few questions.  Why is there a black wire on the ground terminal (A1)?  This is not okay right?  I have done a fair amount of wiring, but this whole mess is stumping me.  It is possible the switch and the outlet have nothing to do with each other, but this outlet was the only box (other than the switch) with a 12/3 wire.  There is a 12/2 wire in the ceiling that was capped off at some point... and my tester just ran out of batteries while doing this.  I'll have to get more batteries tomorrow... anyway.

I'd like to figure out what this switch did or does and rewire it properly if needed, but my ultimate end goal is to keep the outlet working as is and run some lights off the switch.  Any tips on easiest way to do that would be appreciated.

My guesses here: The outlet used to be a switched outlet and at some point it was changed to a non-switched outlet.  Whoever did this was lazy and used the ground terminal for power instead of using a pigtail.  No idea still what the 12/2 in the ceiling did or does.

I'd really appreciate any input, tips, anything.  Thanks again.

[image: switch][image]

Comment: A1 is a no-no, and should be taken off and capped.  Will need to check if A4 and A3 are hot, if they are then A2 can be hot(switched) also.  Would remove all wires from the switch and cap them, check for power first.

Comment: I am color blind but the A1 looks Green to me and it is correctly connected to the ground.

Comment: the red one is usulay the switched hot. I said "usualy"

Comment: Is your black  A1 connected to the ground wires with the green wire nut?

Comment: JACK, the black A1 is not connected to the ground wires.  Sorry the pic makes it hard to see that.

Comment: @Ruskes   I find it better to believe the OP.  There was one picture on here of a bolt/screw/fastener head.  Look at it once and it was a cross cut into the head, look at same picture again it was a cross raised up on the head.  Drove me bonkers.

Comment: @crip659 and. the OP just proved you wrong

Comment: This needs to be [edit]ed to focus on _just_ the switch. Once you have that sorted, ask a second question about the outlet if necessary.

Comment: So, only A3 is hot.  A4 is powering some outlets in another room.  And I only now just remembered there is another switch in the garage that does nothing.  I forgot about it because it's been covered for years with a bunch of stuff.  I bet that and this switch is for the capped 12/2 in the ceiling.  I won't be able to verify for a few days because of work, but I really appreciate all the responses here.

Comment: @Ruskes It's definitely not a ground. You can see the bare copper grounds all tied together with a wire nut inside the box.

Comment: You guys were right, outlet had nothing to do with the switch.  Ended up being a incorrectly wired 3-way switch.  Thanks all!

Comment: @Rich, please write that up as an answer then click the check mark next to the question (once the system allows you to do so). That makes it easier for others to find. Not everyone will read through all the comments to discover it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GFCI box looks reasonable, so I would ignore it and fully diagnose the switch first.

With a multi-meter, carefully check for VAC on every combination of wires attached to the switch.  Wear gloves if necessary.  Assume anything and everything is hot, including the switch and yoke.  If possible, put one of the probes back against the bare grounding wires spliced by the green wire nut.

If you do find any readings more than 1 or 2 VAC, turn off as many circuit breakers as it takes to disconnect all the hot wires in that box.

Once the box is safely un-powered, you can detach all wires from the switch.  Keep the wires separate and pointed in different directions.

With the switch removed, you can turn on the circuit breaker(s) and carefully use the multi-tester to check which of the black and red wires are hot.  Considering the configuration and presence of a switch, there is likely one hot wire, one or two wires feeding power to other outlets, and one or two wires feeding switched lights or receptacles.  The capped cable in the ceiling could be one of the hot or switched hot wires by design, but there's no distinction at this point.

If you can't determine where one of the wires goes, leave it disconnected and insulated when you are done.  This also goes for the capped cable in the ceiling, if the other end is in that switch box it needs to be capped there as well.

A pigtail from the switch ground terminal to the other three ground wires is required and needs to be added here.

Edit: One possible scenario based on the comments is that the garage was originally equipped with a pair of 3-way switches.  Those were later replaced by someone who couldn't tell the difference between a ground terminal and a traveller terminal.  In that case, the paired black and red wires are (hopefully) travellers, with the line and load being other cables.  You would find at least 3 hot or switched hot wires at the other switch in that case, plus the 2 or more white and ground wires.  Both switches will need to be replaced unless you intend to further abandon part of the system.

Comment: Got it, thanks for the response.  I'll get some more batteries for my tester and work on it.

Comment: @Rich It might be relevant if there's a side door in the garage with another switch?  In which case, there might have been a 3-way setup at one time even though you have a 2-way switch in there now.

Comment: So that just reminded me that there is another switch in the garage that did nothing.  I forgot about it because it's been covered up with stuff for years.  I bet that switch and this switch originally was for the 12/2 in the ceiling.  Thanks, I never would have remembered about that old switch without your comment.

Comment: @Rich I added a paragraph to the answer.  I hope you're headed in the right direction and can sort out the numerous wires and their purposes from here.

Comment: Robert, that was exactly what it was.  Once I remembered the other switch, everything made sense.  Both switches were incorrectly wired to single pole switches.  I rewired both switches correctly with a pair of 3-way switches.  Those switches now properly control the 12/2 which was capped in the ceiling.  This will be perfect for me to run some lights from the ceiling box.  Thanks again for all the help.

Comment: @Rich, if that satisfies the original question, the appropriate thing to do now is click the check mark icon next to the answer post to accept it.  I'm glad that helped.